# Continue to next SSIS task if task fails

Tags: ssis

I have a package with tasks that call other packages. I want to run them in sequence instead of in parallel, but it is important that remaining tasks run if one should fail.

[image: PackageCallingOtherPackages]

I have tried adding an OnError Event Handler for each of the tasks. For each of the OnError Event Handlers, I set the Propagate variable to false, but this didn't work. If a task fails, the following tasks don't run

[image: OnError]

Just to test, I added similar OnError Event Handlers to the packages that get called by the Execute Package tasks, but this still didn't work. I have looked up in various websites, but everything I get to points me to what I have already done.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here, of if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe there is a blue line instead of green that means "on Completion" instead of "On Success"

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after I posted this question, I came to a website that gave the answer:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f731a8c6-179c-42b2-b77b-eba203617188/etl-continue-package-execution-after-error-in-ssis?forum=sqldatawarehousing